# "(Web) feed" instead of "RSS"

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently the tag [rss](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rss) is in use.

**Problems**:

- Technically "RSS" is not distinct, because there are [several *different* formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS#Variants) that use this name (they are not merely different versions of the same format!).
- There is also the [Atom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28standard%29) format.

Many users use "RSS" as synonym for "feed", and most of the time (maybe even without knowing it) they also want to create/consume "Atom" feeds.

**Suggestions**:

1. Use the tag "feed" ([feed](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feed)) or "Web feed" ([web-feed](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-feed)) instead. (Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_feed)
2. Add [rss](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rss) (and possibly [atom](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atom)) as synonym (or just delete [rss](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rss))

If someone requires only a specific feed format, the tag can still be added, and the question lists exactly which format is required.

Comment: Are there any RSS feed clients that don't work with all 2(3?) RSS formats?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: I don’t know (if you need one, I could create one that only supports a specific format ;-)). If they use common feed libraries, usually all feed formats are supported. If they code it on their own, it might depend on the developer (here’s an older blog post describing [incompatibilites between the "RSS" formats](http://web.archive.org/web/20110726001954/http://diveintomark.org/archives/2004/02/04/incompatible-rss))

Comment: More importantly, are there realistically any questions today that may suffer if the tag says rss instead of web-feed?